# When/where a subview of UIView is initialized from storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a subclass of UIView `class AView: UIView` and drag a UIView to storyboard `UIViewController` interface builder file, change the class name to `AView`, then i drag another 2 `UIView`s on the AView assign tag 10, 11.

My question is when both subviews was **created** and **initialized**?

```
class AView: UIView{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       print(self.subviews)
    } 
    override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      print(self.subviews)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      print(self.subviews)
    }
}
```

Only `layoutSubviews` print the subviews. Of course it should be. As documentation said seems the subviews has been created before this method:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing on iOS 5.1 and earlier. Otherwise, the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.
>   Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

Another question if `super.layoutSubviews()` is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

When a nib file is loaded, first thing that happens is individual objects are loaded first, and initWithCoder is sent to them so that they can be initialised. Note that the object graph is not yet connected here. This is the exact reason, if you try to access subviews in init, you won't find any. So is the case with awakeFromNib that is called on to this view, it is only an indication that view is now loaded, but yet the object graph need not have been connected yet at this point.

To quote documentation on awakeFromNib-

> The order in which the nib-loading code calls the awakeFromNib methods
>   of objects is not guaranteed. In OS X, Cocoa tries to call the
>   awakeFromNib method of File’s Owner last but does not guarantee that
>   behavior. If you need to configure the objects in your nib file
>   further at load time, the most appropriate time to do so is after your
>   nib-loading call returns. At that point, all of the objects are
>   created, initialized, and ready for use.

System calls layoutSubviews before it can actually present them or finds a re -org is needed, and here all object graph would have been connected by the nib loading process. So, you can access any view here and position/size it if you want by overriding. It is very important to call super.layoutSubviews before you do any changes.

**Now coming to the question of when exactly all views are initialised and available for me to access?-**

1. If we are loading via view controllers, then viewDidLoad is the place where every object from nib has been loaded and all outlets are connected, etc.
2. If we are loading the nib ourselves, it will be only after the nib loading call returns.

Comment: Seems it's not correct, even i connected still print nil for AView's subviews. Even if i don't connected there must be a time the subviews be were initialised, the connect is just a reference, isn't it?